# iPhone Numeric Keypad with Decimal for web apps?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, forms

I know with native iPhone apps you can use UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad to force a numeric keypad with a decimal. Is there any way to force this same keypad for an input field on a mobile webpage or web application? If not yet, does anyone know if this detection will be added to Safari in iOS 6?

I am able to display the regular numeric keypad without issues, but I'd really like to have the decimal key so I don't need to display the full keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up using one of the below solutions?

Comment: No, it's not possible to bring up this keyboard from the web still.

Answer (score 12):

Checkout `inputmode="decimal"` attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Not widely supported yet but it comes available in iOS 12.2.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I needed! Using type="number" bring up full keyboard (with letters, etc)... I needed only numeric keyboard, but with decimal!

Answer (score 9):

This is not possible, however there is a slight hack, which you can use.

Look at this link - http://web.archive.org/web/20151110014447/http://www.brownphp.com/2011/05/iphone-currency-input-web-apps/

Once the user starts writing/typing in the field it starts adding the numbers this way - 0.01 -> 0.12 -> 1.23 -> 12.34 . So this can be used for similar effect.

Also here is a overview of the input types for web apps, where you can see it is not possible to use the input type with numbers and a decimal point.

http://www.fabianpimminger.com/web-development/how-to-change-the-iphone-on-screen-keyboard-in-web-apps/

Comment: unfortunately the first link included is 404'ing :(

Answer (score 3):

Add inputmode="decimal" attribute to the input tag.

```
<input id="price" type="number" min="0" inputmode="decimal">
```

Check other input modes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode

Answer (score 0):

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html) lists `number` as an input type:

> A text field for specifying a number. Brings up a number pad keyboard in iOS 3.1 and later. Specifying an input type of \d* or [0-9]* is equivalent to using this type.

Comment: Thanks, yes this will display the regular numeric keypad (no decimal button), but not the special numeric keypad which includes the decimal. I'm trying to get the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad keypad that is available to native iOS apps to display when tapping a webform.

Comment: Ah yes I see, I assumed `number` included a decimal button.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `number` is that it will only accept integers. I found [this](http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/) where he mentions adding `step="any"`. Now you get the numeric keypad and can enter decimals.

Comment: Unfortunately type="number" still brings up the regular alphanumeric keypad. You have to use type="tel" or use pattern="\d*" to get the numeric keypad so this doesn't work! Thanks though.

Comment: Actually I'm not 100% correct. It brings up another keyboard I've never seen that is numbers, but with lots of extra characters like hyphen, brackets, $, &, @, etc. I was hoping for the telephone style number pad with the nice big easy to press buttons, and then a decimal in the bottom left corner.